# how to find minimum & maximum values latitude and longitude on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to locate the minimum latitude/longitude & maximum latitude/longitude value of visible region region of Google map.For eg: if i drag the map along any axis than at drag end, java script will alert me with minimum/maximum latitude/longitude values.

Answer (score 4):

You can hook an event listener for Map -> idle event:

> This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or
>   zooming.

Inside that event you can call the `Map.getBounds()` method. You can then use the `LatLngBounds.getNorthEast()` and `LatLngBounds.getSouthWest()` methods to get the top-left and bottom right corners of the visible region.

- [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/HBBb8/)
- [google.maps.Map reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)
- [google.maps.LatLngBounds reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds)

Answer (score 2):

Use google.maps.Map#getBounds

For example:

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-div'), { /* options */});

var bounds = map.getBounds();`

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map